# Connected to wifi but can't ping router (or anything else)

Tags: linux, fedora, wifi-configuration, networkmanager

I have a little bit of a different setup, I'm on a laptop with 3 OSes installed, Windows 10, Gentoo and Fedora 36. In both Gentoo and Fedora I use NetworkManager to manages wifi etc. I installed Gentoo first and have never had any problems with networks there, but when I installed Fedora I started to run into problems. There is no problem with connecting to a wireless network, and it usually works for a while, but suddenly, it stops working. It still says that I'm connected to the network, but I'm not able to ping anything, not even my router. I thought the router had problems differentiating between Gentoo and Fedora, so I changed MAC-address on the Fedora install (i.e. temporarily changed it everytime I booted). And it worked without problems a couple of days, but then I started to run into the same problem. If I change the MAC-address and restart NetworkManager, it always starts working again, if I just restart NetworkManager, it will sometimes start working. I've compared the setups, and there is no difference (except that Gentoo uses OpenRC (instead of SystemD) to start NetworkManager). Sometimes things work for several hours, sometimes just a few minutes. Sometimes I get the error "ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available" (but just a few times), but trying to look up that error didn't help.

A few more clarifications/things I've tried

- Disabling Ipv6
- Removing the network in Gentoo
- Sometimes when I try to ping right after restarting NetworkManager, exactly one ping gets through
- It is not a problem with DNS
- Before the Gentoo/Fedora combo, I used Ubuntu without problems
- I've tried reinstalling Fedora
- I've had a similar problem with bluetooth, where I needed to start it in Windows to be able to use bluetooth in Linux.
- It still says that I've an IP-address when I lose router connection
- There is no problem with the wifi on any other device in the network
- Firmware is up to date

And here is where I'm stuck. It is really frustrating when it disconnects during video-meetings, I have no idea of how to continue.

All help is appreciated

Comment: If this is a triple boot system, then each system would be treated separately. Do all operating systems have the same failure?  Yes may mean hardware error.

Comment: @John It is only a problem in Fedora.

Comment: Try replacing the Wireless driver in Fedora.

Comment: I've tried downgrading the kernel (albeit not to the same as I used on Ubuntu or Gentoo), and when I built my own kernel for Gentoo I found my wireless card in the config, so I'm assuming that support for it is included in the 5.18-fedora-build. I'm using 5.17 now. but it is the same problem when booting, i.e. after boot I always have to restart the network interface. It is hard to tell if the sudden disconnects are present, because it will sometimes work flawlessly for a while. Not sure of how to replace individual drivers, I assume they are in the kernel itself.

Comment: Try the wireless card manufacturer’s website for the Linux driver

Comment: I will try that. Faulty drivers may be the problem, I get the same error as in this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/210451/what-does-ping-sendmsg-no-buffer-space-available-mean , where they also suggest that it may be drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a driver issue in Fedora. It is solved by using the  [open source drivers for RTL88x2CE found here on github](https://github.com/juanro49/rtl88x2ce-dkms). I did have some problems with kernel headers not being installed correctly, but after rebooting it started working. My network card is Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter. I have no idea why it doesn't work since I tried changing kernel version and gotten it to work flawlessly on other distros. I do have a few problems with these open source drivers as well, if the laptop suspends it will won't recognize the Network Card at all (not showing up on `lspci -k`), but it is solved with a reboot (which is also a tip for anyone trying to install them, if you get stuck, reboot, since it is drivers something must be loaded in to the kernel correctly, which is often accomplished when booting).

As an update, it works much better (without any external drivers) in recent versions of Fedora, although every now and then the issue reappears.